# App crashes only on one device. When accessing image from gallery returns null and not uri

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created application that takes photo from gallery and puts in listview. But cause I need some metadata I need to take pick manually. I take uri of photo and than convert it to path. Everything is pretty fine, but on only one device "Xiaomi readmi 4a" Android 6.0 it crashes. Probably cause I get null and not a actual uri. I've tested on android 5.0-9.0 emulators, and 7.1, 8.0 physical devices

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Intent = new Intent();
        Intent.SetType("image/*");
        Intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);
        StartActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(Intent, "Select Picture"), PickImageId);

    }

    protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok) && (data != null))
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
            path = GetPathToImage(uri);
            Mesasge(path);
            Finish();

        }
    }

    private string GetPathToImage(Android.Net.Uri uri)
    {
        string doc_id;
        using (var c1 = ContentResolver.Query(uri, null, null, null, null))
        {
            c1.MoveToFirst();
            string document_id = c1.GetString(0);
            doc_id = document_id.Substring(document_id.LastIndexOf(":") + 1);
        }

        string path = null;

        string selection = Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Id + " =? ";
        using (var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.ExternalContentUri, null, selection, new string[] { doc_id }, null))
        {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
            { 
                var columnIndex = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(Android.Provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.InterfaceConsts.Data);
                path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
                cursor.Close();
            }
        }
        return path;
    }
```

It sends this error message "android.database.cursorindexoutofboundsexception index 0 requested with a size of 0" if I don't check `(cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())`, else I get just null in return

I've tried every solution for it, but problem is not in cursor.

I don't know how even detect the problem, cause this device is far away from me, and I can't send everything in Logcat to see what the problem is.

Comment: i have an Redmi Note 7 and sometimes, even if i accept permissions, it won't activate them, so make sure that your app has acess to the galery

Comment: If you take a look at the code that James uses to select a picture in this plugin, https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin there's a lot of checks that need to be made since the Android media framework is fragmented. I would suggest using the plugin for selecting media instead, and following instructions to setting it up from there

Comment: @Saamer I need original photo, not copy that this plugin make. I can't even take creation date from it

Comment: @Yuudachi,About select photo from gallery, I find one article about use media plugin in your project:https://lalorosas.com/blog/xamarin-forms-selecting-image-from-the-gallery

Comment: @Cherry Bu I need original photo, not copy that this plugin make. I can't even take creation date from it

Answer (score 0):

I can't really tell you what to do since you can't test it, except maybe suggest a few changes like this

```
if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Result.Ok))
{
    if (data.Data == null)
    {
        var clipData = data.ClipData;
        for (int i = 0; i < clipData.ItemCount; i++)
        {
            var item = clipData.GetItemAt(i);
            Android.Net.Uri uri = item.Uri;
            path = GetPathToImage(uri);
            Mesasge(path);
            Finish();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Android.Net.Uri uri = data.Data;
        path = GetPathToImage(uri);
        Mesasge(path);
        Finish();
    }
}
```